# Error While Creating Build

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have TFS 2010 and for one of the team project I have created the build definition (used default build template) and added the solution of one of the project. But when try to create build getting the following error:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets
>   (902): The          command "if Debug == Debug copy
>   "C:\Builds\14\\\Sources\ServerObjects..\SharedInterfaces\bin\debug*.dll"
>   "C:\Builds\14\\\Sources\ServerObjects..\ServerObjects\bin\debug"" exited with
>   code 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you maybe has wrong folder structure on the source control, see my answer on similar question here

[teambuilding and deploying a dll (e.g. wpftoolkit.extended.dll)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693159/teambuilding-and-deploying-a-dll-e-g-wpftoolkit-extended-dll/9697996#9697996)

Answer (score 0):

TeamBuild overrides the output folder so the bin\debug (or bin\release) folder won't exist.  It collates the output into Binaries.

For your custom build step use the obj folder instead of bin as that'll be the same under both TeamBuild and the local machine build.